# SomeObject is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces

Tags: java, jaxb

In my application there is a tree of objects. To constitute that tree every object has a parent reference.  Since certain object types can be child of several parent object types all potential parent object types are unified by implementing a common interface.
I narrowed down the problem (JAXB complains about the parent member variable (annotated @XmlIDREF and @XmlAttribute) being an interface) as much as I could:

```
public interface Parent{
    @XmlID
    @XmlAttribute( name = "oid" )
    public String getID();
    public void setID( String id );
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.NONE )
public class ChildObject implements Parent{
    @XmlTransient
    private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();

    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlAttribute
    protected Parent parent = null;

    public ChildObject() {}

    public ChildObject( Parent parent ){
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @XmlID
    @XmlAttribute
    @Override
    public String getID(){ return( id.toString() ); }

    @Override
    public void setID( String id ){ this.id = UUID.fromString( id ); }
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.NONE )
public class Repository{

    @XmlElement
    private List<ChildObject> objects = new ArrayList<>();

    public Repository() {}

    public ChildObject addObject( ChildObject o ){
        objects.add( o );
        return( o );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        Repository r = new Repository();
        ChildObject root = r.addObject( new ChildObject() );
        ChildObject c0 = r.addObject( new ChildObject( root ) );
        ChildObject c1 = r.addObject( new ChildObject( root ) );
        ChildObject c11 = r.addObject( new ChildObject( c1 ) );
        ChildObject c12 = r.addObject( new ChildObject( c1 ) );
        try{ 
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance( Repository.class );
            Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty( Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true );
            marshaller.marshal( r, System.out );
        }catch( Exception ex ){ ex.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

This is the exception I get, when trying to run it:

> com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1
>   counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions Parent is an interface, and JAXB
>   can't handle interfaces.  this problem is related to the following
>   location:         at Parent       at protected Parent ChildObject.parent      at
>   ChildObject       at private java.util.List Repository.objects        at
>   Repository
>
> at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:91)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:445)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.(JAXBContextImpl.java:277)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.(JAXBContextImpl.java:124)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1123)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:147)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:247)  at
>   javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:234)  at
>   javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:462)     at
>   javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:641)  at
>   javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)  at
>   Repository.main(Repository.java:33)

Is this the intended behavior of JAXB (or is it a bug) and  what am I supposed to do to get around it?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by adding a dummy `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` to the interface like so:

```
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.NONE )
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ChildObject.ParentAdapter.class)
public interface Parent{
    @XmlID
    @XmlAttribute( name = "oid" )
    public abstract String getID();
    public abstract void setID( String id );
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.NONE )
public class ChildObject implements Parent{

    @XmlTransient
    private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();

    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlAttribute
    protected Parent parent = null;

    public ChildObject() {}

    public ChildObject( Parent parent ){
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @XmlID
    @XmlAttribute( name = "oid" )
    @Override
    public String getID(){ return( id.toString() ); }

    @Override
    public void setID( String id ){ this.id = UUID.fromString( id ); }


    public static class ParentAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Object,Object>{
        @Override
        public Object marshal( Object arg0 ) throws Exception{ return arg0; }

        @Override
        public Object unmarshal( Object arg0 ) throws Exception{ return arg0; }
    }
}
```

Still, I'm not sure whether this is a bug or the intended behavior of JAXB (Oracle JDK 8u121)

Comment: Annotating the interface with `@XmlTransient` works too. No need for the empty `XmlAdapter`